# Mnist with Tensorflow Premade Estimator, input dimension mismatch on evaluate

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am rather new to Tensorflow, and has been trying to pick up the basics by reading through the guides and documentation on tensorflow.org

I have learnt the basics of how to use the `tf.data` and `tf.estimator` APIs and is trying to get them to work together on a basic classification model for MNIST.

I am using this script to load MNIST: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/mnist/dataset.py

I made modifications to the dataset function to return a feature dictionary rather than vector:

```
def dataset(directory, images_file, labels_file):
  """Download and parse MNIST dataset."""

  images_file = download(directory, images_file)
  labels_file = download(directory, labels_file)

  check_image_file_header(images_file)
  check_labels_file_header(labels_file)

  def decode_image(image):
    # Normalize from [0, 255] to [0.0, 1.0]
    image = tf.decode_raw(image, tf.uint8)
    image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
    image = tf.reshape(image, [784])
    return image / 255.0

  def decode_label(label):
    label = tf.decode_raw(label, tf.uint8)  # tf.string -> [tf.uint8]
    label = tf.reshape(label, [])  # label is a scalar
    return tf.to_int32(label)

  images = tf.data.FixedLengthRecordDataset(
      images_file, 28 * 28, header_bytes=16).map(decode_image)
  labels = tf.data.FixedLengthRecordDataset(
      labels_file, 1, header_bytes=8).map(decode_label)
  return tf.data.Dataset.zip(({"image":images}, labels))
```

My MNIST classifier script using the premade estimator in tf is as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import dataset

fc = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column("image", shape=784)]

mnist_classifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
    hidden_units=[512,512],
    feature_columns=fc,
    model_dir="models/mnist/dnn",
    n_classes=10)

def input_fn(train=False, batch_size=None):
    if train:
        ds = mnist.train("MNIST-data")
        ds = ds.shuffle(1000).repeat().batch(batch_size)
    else:
        ds = mnist.test("MNIST-data")
    return ds

mnist_classifier.train(
  input_fn=lambda:input_fn(True, 32),
  steps=10000)

eval_results = mnist_classifier.evaluate(input_fn=lambda:input_fn())
```

The classifier doesn't crash on training, but on evaluate, I faced the following traceback:

> ValueError: Cannot reshape a tensor with 784 elements to shape
>   [784,784] (614656 elements) for
>   'dnn/input_from_feature_columns/input_layer/image/Reshape' (op:
>   'Reshape') with input shapes: [784,1], [2] and with input tensors
>   computed as partial shapes: input[1] = [784,784].

What could be causing the issue here?

I have tried printing the output shapes and types of both train and test datasets, and they are exactly the same.

I have also tried viewing the model on tensorboard, and only the projector tab is available, no scalars or graphs tab.

Thanks!

PS: Any links to TF tutorials using the Datasets and Estimators APIs will be great too.

Comment: output_shapes and output_types for train and test datasets:
`({'image': TensorShape([Dimension(784)])}, TensorShape([]))`
`({'image': tf.float32}, tf.int32)`

Comment: Pardon me `mnist.train` and `mnist.test` should be replaced with `dataset.train` and `dataset.test` respectively. I renamed the dataset.py to mnist.py in my PC, forgot the change it while copy-pasting on posting. The error is still present though.

Comment: did you manage to find the problem? I'm having a similar issue.

Comment: @BahmanRouhani
Yes, I managed to identify the issue.
You'll need to batch the data from the test input function as well.

In the else clause of input_fn (for test input):
`ds = mnist.test("MNIST-data").batch(batch_size)`